# JetBrains IDE how configure multi language file

Tags: jetbrains-ide

There are files in the project that contain three languages: Python, HTML, JS.
Languages ​​are between special tags

```
<mako>
from pyasm.search import Search
</mako>
```

```
<html>
<div style="padding-left: 10px;">Hi</div>
</html>
```

```
<behavior>
var el = header_el.getElement(".spt_header_account_top");
</behavior>
```

How to associate these tags with required syntax in PyCharm IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating the corresponding [language injections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2019.2/using-language-injections.html): create new *XML Tag* injection in **Settings | Editor | Language Injections**, specify your tag name (`behavior`, for example) as *Local name:*, choose the desired language (`JavaScript`, for example) as *ID:*.

You can also inject languages in your tags using **Inject language or reference** intention available on `Alt+Enter`:

[image]